# kml connect placemarks with a solid line

Tags: python, google-maps, maps, line, kml

i've written a [kml](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) file full of placemarks with name, description and coordinates. It's structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <name>test</name>
  <description><![CDATA[test]]></description>
        <Placemark>
            <name>name 1</name>
            <description>description 1</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>18.70669,36.12645</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
            <name>name 2</name>
            <description>description 2</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>18.70513,36.12698</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The only way I found to connect them is by using `<MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>` but I'm looking for a smarter and smaller solution.
A python script would be accepted as a solution too.

Comment: why can't you just use `<MultiGeometry><LineString><coordinates>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, all you're looking to do is connect the two coordinates with a line? If so, all you need to do is use `<LineString>`:

```
<LineString id="geom_842">
    <coordinates>18.70669,36.12645,0.0 18.70513,36.12698,0.0 </coordinates>
</LineString>
```

Using python from the [documentation](http://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#creating-a-kml-document):

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
lin = kml.newlinestring(name="name", description="description",
      coords=[(18.70669,36.12645), (18.70513,36.12698)])
kml.save('filename.kml')
```